# Abstract proof simple group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that a finite $p$-group $G$ is simple if and only if |$G$|=$p$.

We have $G$$\neq${$1$} and $G$ has no normal subgroups other than {$1$} and $G$ itself for it to be simple.

So if |$G$|=$p$ then $G$$\neq${$1$} correct?
and since $p$ is prime, for it to be a normal it has to equal itself hence $G$=$G$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be a simple finite $p$-group. Consider the orbits of the operation of $G$ on itself by conjugation. The length of each orbit is either a multiple (in fact power) of $p$ or is $1$. The latter is the case exactly for elements of the center $C$ of $G$. We conclude that $|C|$ is a multiple of $p$, i.e. $C\ne 1$. As $C\lhd G$, we conclude $C=G$, i.e. $G$ is abelian. Any subgroup of an abelian group is normal, hence if $a\in G$ has order $p$, $\langle a\rangle \lhd G$ implies $G=\langle a\rangle$ and hence $|G|=p$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be a simple group such that $|G|=p^n,~ n\ge 2$ and let $H<G$ be a subgroup of order $p^{n-1}$. This subgroup exists for tis $p$ group (Why?). We can find a nice contradiction -which is a bit similar to @Hagen's way- for the group $G$. That is the following fact:

> Theorem: If $|G|=m$ and $p$ be a smallest prime number dividing $|G|$ then every subgroup of $G$ of index $p$,  is a normal subgroup.

Comment: ╋Thanks for your answer✔

Comment: How'd I miss this one? I thought I $\uparrow$ 'ed all your posts! +++++++++